# NAS4Free disk encryption and ZFS error

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage, encryption, zfs, truenas

I have installed a NAS4Free on a VM, and as recommended, I installed it on a 1GB virtual disk, and assigned another disk 500GB to this VM for file storage.

I have created the disk, encrypted it, created a ZFS virtual disk, and then a ZFS storage pool. Everything was working. On every restart of this VM I needed to go on and mount the encrypted drive.

Recently I upgraded the host machine, and now I can't mount or make it work. I have tried removing everything and setting up from scratch everything, with the exception of formatting the disk.  I have used an encrypted one without formatting it.

Does anybody have any suggestion on how I can at least get back my data?  Can I somehow mount the encrypted drive even in another utility, just need to get back the data that was on it?

Comment: More details please

Comment: Sure yeah, the following appears in the ZFS Storage Pool, and the mounted disk does not appear anywhere:
Name: StoragePool;
Size: Unknown;
Used: Unknown;
Free: Unknown;
Capacity: Unknown;
Dedup: Unknown;
Health: Unknown;
AltRoot: Unknown

Answer (score 1):

This one fixed my problem :)
http://forums.nas4free.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1271

After added the disk has ZFS pool in disk management...

Go to

> ZFS > Configuration > Detected > import > import again (force to imported has it adviced) ...

the configuration will appear.

Go to

> ZFS > Synchronise to apply the configuration.